# Wine error: "fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f4b4,0x00000000), stub!"

Tags: wine

### Error:

I am trying to run application by wine, and get error:

```
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f4b4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d_surface:surface_init Trying to create a render target that isn't in the default pool.
fixme:winediag:AUDDRV_GetAudioEndpoint Winepulse is not officially supported by the wine project
fixme:winediag:AUDDRV_GetAudioEndpoint For sound related feedback and support, please visit http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1960599
fixme:d3d_surface:wined3d_surface_flip Ignoring flags 0x1.
```

How to solve this?

### System Info:

Ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Wine version:

```
wine --version
wine-1.6.2
```

Graphic card:

```
sudo lshw -C video[sudo] hasło użytkownika daniel: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look up your application in the Wine HQ database ?

https://appdb.winehq.org

Is your application suppose to run reasonably well in Wine or is it not in the database at all ?

I prefer to use PlayOnLinux instead of plain Wine whenever I would need to run some native Windows application. PlayOnLinux has a nice GUI, and with PlayOnLinux you will be able to switch between different Wine versions quite easily.
Some native Windows programs need a specific Wine version to run well.
In some other Wine version, the native Windows program might simply crash or exit really soon.
Search for PlayOnLinux, and install the deb, and try it.

Good luck!

Comment: I found this https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30877 it works for wine 1.7.24, so I understood, that I should install newest wine.

Comment: Good that you found an entry in the Wine HQ database. The one review however shows that the game is impossible to play with Wine 1.7.24. So you might want to try with different Wine versions, which can easily be done with PlayOnLinux.  Another thing you can try is to install ReactOS inside qemu/KVM or VirtualBox. ReactOS is still in heavy development but it can run several 32 bit Windows applications very well, like Firefox and LibreOffice.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReactOS . If you do have a Microsoft Windows license, you could install VirtualBox, or run Microsoft Windows in qemu/KVM.

Comment: Ok. You are right. It doe's not working correctly. I was trying install on VirtalBox. Application is ok, but latency on mouse make it hard to use.